# RubyMine 3.0 setup on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-7, rubymine, mysql2

All,

I downloaded/installed 1.9.2 windows installer, and then RubyMine3.0RC, and installed it.

Opening a new Rails project, with mysql selected as the DB, gives the following error when I "RUN" it.

```
D:\ProgramFiles\Ruby192\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:/Users/Rob/RubymineProjects/test1/script/rails server -p 3000 -b 127.0.0.1 -e development
D:/ProgramFiles/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `require': 126: The specified module could not be found.   - D:/ProgramFiles/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/1.9/mysql2.so (LoadError)
    from D:/ProgramFiles/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/ProgramFiles/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:7:in `require'
    from D:/ProgramFiles/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/ProgramFiles/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:64:in `require'
    from D:/ProgramFiles/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from D:/ProgramFiles/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `each'
    from D:/ProgramFiles/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `block in require'
    from D:/ProgramFiles/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:51:in `each'
    from D:/ProgramFiles/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:51:in `require'
    from D:/ProgramFiles/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler.rb:112:in `require'
    from C:/Users/Rob/RubymineProjects/test1/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/ProgramFiles/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
    from D:/ProgramFiles/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from D:/ProgramFiles/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from D:/ProgramFiles/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Users/Rob/RubymineProjects/test1/script/rails:6:in `require'
    from C:/Users/Rob/RubymineProjects/test1/script/rails:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Is this supposed to happen?  I have installed the mysql2 gem as well, but still seeing these messages in the console.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure you have **libmysql.dll** from the 5.1.x 32-bit MySQL distribution in PATH or in RUBY_HOME\bin directory.

If it doesn't help, you may have better luck reporting the issue at the [mysql2 gem project homepage](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2).

Comment: http://blog.mmediasys.com/2009/07/06/getting-started-with-rails-and-mysql/   >>>  this helped me alot ... found it through a bug in the project homepage link you provided ... thanks.

Comment: Just needed to copy libmysql.dll from mysql library to the /bin directory in Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, I was able to fix the error by copying "libmySQL.dll" file from 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin' to 'C:\Ruby192\bin'. 
For details, refer to post - http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/03/getting-error-specified-module-could.html