# Ruby on Rails isn't allowing me to run app through localhost:3000

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to connect my app to localhost:3000 to try and run ruby on rails but when I put localhost:3000 into browser it downloads a file.  So when I kept looking for something to resolve this problem it kept saying to go and do a bundle install and then after it's done it then says error and says try and install 'gem install mysql2 -v 0.3.14 before bundling.  So i do that and go and bundle install again and it gives me the same error

Comment: No it just says "Gem files will remain installed in...." and then says "Results logged to...."

Comment: and I did both and it still gives me the same thing

Comment: when going to localhost:3000 or http://localhost:3000 it just downloads a file

Comment: what do you mean by system/enviroment?

Comment: What file does it download?

Comment: J   
5.6.15 0   %eRK^vX4 ÿ÷! €          <p?(K!`AbL6g mysql_native_password !  ÿ„#08S01Got packets out of order

Comment: What operating system, what ruby version, what rails version, what bundler version, what mysql version?

Comment: wind 8.1, ruby 1.9.6, rails 4.0.2, doesn't tell me bundler version, mysql2 -v 0.3.14

Answer (score 0):

the problem seems like `bundler` cannot install `mysql2` gem, thats why bundler says to install it explicitly .

try run `gem install mysql2` and see what are the errors you are getting. I'm not sure about windows but in linux the common problem is lack of header files.

and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946902/installing-mysql2-gem-on-windows-8) might also give you some hint..