# Rails Development- MySQL Connection Problems

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mysql-error-1045

I'm new in Rails. I tried a lot to solve my problem with the answers given in this site, but failed.

**1.My configurations**

`Window 7 64bit`
`ruby 1.9.3p484`
`rails 4.0.2`
`mysql server 5.0.91-community-nt (32bit)`
`mysql gem`
`I set a password for root in mysql configuration`

**2.I created a new application**
`rails new my_cms -d mysql`
I made two changes
1. Inside Gemfile I use mysql instead of mysql2
2. Inside config/database.yml I use mysql instead of mysql2

**3. config/database.yml content**

```
development:
  adapter: mysql  
  encoding: utf8  
  database: mycms_development  
  pool: 5  
  username: root  
  password:  
  host: 127.0.0.1  
  port: 3306

test:
  adapter: mysql2  
  encoding: utf8  
  database: mycms_test  
  pool: 5  
  username: root  
  password:  
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: mysql2  
  encoding: utf8  
  database: mycms_production  
  pool: 5  
  username: root  
  password:  
  host: localhost
```

**4.Running server**
`rails s`
server running.
**5.opening browser and typing** `localhost:3000`**ERROR like below**

```
Mysql::Error
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Rails.root: E:/cms/mycms
```

**6.My efforts to solve the error**
I tried my best to crack the error as guided here.
    **TRY=>** changed 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, added port: 3306
    **RESULT=>** `Mysql::Error`
                `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`
                 `Rails.root: E:/cms/mycms`

**TRY=>** put my password as root password field inside config/database.yml file
    **RESULT=>**`ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished`

**TRY=>** executed `mysql -uroot`
**RESULT=>** `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

**TRY=>** Created a new user `vipin` and grant all privileges and executed `mysql -uvipin`
**RESULT=>** `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'vipin'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

**TRY=>** executed `mysql -uroot -p`
**RESULT=>** `password:` and when i gave the password it successfully direct to mysql> prompt.

I dont know what is next. Please help. Thank you

**EDIT**
CURRENT STATUS WHEN ENTERING `localhost:3000`

[image]

Comment: had the same or similar problem on a machine, gave up after 2h. Would be nice to see a solution

Comment: Why did you opt to use `mysql` instead of `mysql2`?  `mysql2` is much faster.

Comment: Need a solution. I think its the problem of mysql version. But I am not sure. Need REAL HELP to proceed with my project.

Comment: I assume you redacted the password for posting here, but I need to confirm that it is actually in your `database.yml`.  The error indicates the password is not being sent when it should.

Comment: @Eugene I failed to install mysql2 gem on my Windows machine

Comment: @Eugene my password is `vipings` and set that in `database.yml` file.

Comment: @Eugene When i tried `gem install mysql2` it end up with `ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`  `extconf.rb failed`.  No mysql2 gem is installed while checked with `gem list`

Comment: Are you able to authenticate with `mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -p`?

Comment: +1 for complete info.. in console: `mysqladmin -u root -p ping`  and enter pwd and then it should return `mysqld is alive`  ..

Comment: Try `gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby`

Comment: @Eugene No.  Will try now.

Comment: @Eugene `mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -p` it asks my password and bring me to MySQL monitor.

Comment: @Eugene When I open up my browser and type localhost:3000 ERROR  `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished`  my database.yml content is  development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: mycms_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:vipin
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306  test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: mycms_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 
  host: localhost
  port: 3306

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: mycms_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost

Comment: @Nithin I tried your suggestion. yes. it returned `mysqld is alive`

Comment: http://blog.mmediasys.com/2011/07/07/installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it/

Comment: @Anand Thanks for your support. But installed a different mysql version as I mentioned in my question. When i execute `require "mysql"` in IRB it returns `true`.   But when i execute `conn = Mysql.connect "localhost", "root", "vipin" ` it returns error `Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'(10061)`

Comment: @Anand should i needs to reinstall mysql as shown in the guide..? will it help...?

Comment: You could try that, the version you are currently running is 5.0.91 while the latest version is around 5.5.x

Answer (score 1):

Try to set password and host for test environment too:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql  
  encoding: utf8  
  database: mycms_development  
  pool: 5  
  username: root  
  password: vipin 
  host: localhost  
  port: 3306

test:
  adapter: mysql  
  encoding: utf8  
  database: mycms_test  
  pool: 5  
  username: root  
  password: vipin
  host: localhost
  port: 3306

production:
  adapter: mysql  
  encoding: utf8  
  database: mycms_production  
  pool: 5  
  username: root  
  password:  
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
```

If doesn't work try `host: 127.0.0.1`

Anyway I recommend to to use MySQL 5.5 and the mysql2 gem.
to install that gem have a look this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014117/ruby-mysql2-gem-installation-on-windows-7).

Or you can try BitMani Ruby Stack Installer for windows.

[Ruby Stack Installer](http://bitnami.com/stack/ruby/installer)

[BitMani wiki](http://wiki.bitnami.com/Infrastructure_Stacks/BitNami_Ruby_Stack)

Comment: I uninstalled mysql. Installed a fresh copy `MySQL 5.5 32bit`  . I have `libmysql which is copied from mysql-connector 32 bit`. Now i tried to run `rails s` shows error. 
`E:\cms\mycms>rails s
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.9.1-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql.rb:4:in require: Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 6.0.0 but the client library is 6.1.3. (RuntimeError)` Then I tried to install mysql2 with the command from the link u gave. But it does not works. There is no solution..?

Comment: And about Bitnami stack.. I finally tried that after uninstalled mysql,deleted the installation files, program data. The server is running. But it shows access denied error. And one thing is noted. when i typed the command `mysql -u root' shows the same error as in localhost:3000

Answer (score 0):

Try going into `mysql -u root` and doing `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mycms_development.* TO root@localhost

Comment: As I told in the question, I tried `mysql -u root` and end up with an error `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` Thanks for your support.

Comment: But `mysql -u root -p` is asking the password.

Comment: Now `localhost:3000` showing the error  `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished`