# MySQL Ruby Gem installation error

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems

I can't install the MySQL gem. I know this is a very common error but I have searched and tried everything I could. I have been trying to fix it for more than a week and I am very frustrated. I am working on Windows 7 64-bit machine.

I have tried this: http://blog.mmediasys.com/2011/07/07/installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it/

And moving the libmysql.dll to the bin folder of the ruby installation and still no success.
I also tried 64 bit and 32 bit versions.
I would love to get this problem out of the way to actually start learning...

I will answer as fast as possible to provide any information you need.

Thank you very much, whoever solves it will be my hero!

**EDIT**: Here is the error I am getting. It is very common.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk8CN.jpg

**EDIT: FIXED**
I ended up using:
 `gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-dir="C:\mysql-connector"'`

And this time it worked! I hope this can help anyone with this problem.
[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014117/ruby-mysql2-gem-installation-on-windows-7)

Comment: Would you show us the error message the installation fails with?

Comment: Sooner or later you'll feel the need to move onto a more robust development environment.Not discouraging you from using Windows, but you could spend the time developing things rather than fighting them. Install Ubuntu guest O/S using VMWare Player or Virtualbox and start developing.

Comment: @mudasobwa Just added a screencapture.
I wouldn't mind using Linux, I already do for other things but it should be possible to develop in Windows and the tutorial I am following is focused on Windows so I would like to get it solved.