# Installation Error - Rails MySQL2 Gems on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mysql2

I am not able to install the latest version of mysql2 gem for my rails application. I have already tried out the options suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014117/ruby-mysql2-gem-installation-on-windows-7). However the older version installed without any errors!
    gem uninstall mysql2
    gem install mysql2 -v 0.2.6

**Following is the error that pops up whenever I try to install the latest version of mysql2 gem**

```
C:\Users\EcoAd>gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.16' -- '--with-mysql-lib="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib" --with-mysql-include="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\include"'

Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions with: '--with-mysql-lib="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib" --with-mysql-include="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\include"'

This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20140923-3596-odrqgn.rb extconf.rb --with-mysql-lib="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib" --with-mysql-include="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\include"

checking for ruby/thread.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
```

---

### Using --with-mysql-dir=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6

```
checking for main() in -llibmysql... yes
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes

creating Makefile

make  clean
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.16 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.1/mysql2-0.3.16/gem_make.out
```

C:\Users\EcoAd>