# Install MySQL2 gem on windows8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mysql2

I'm trying to install mysql2 gem but I'm having a problem, I know that there are many posts about it, but I tryed those solutions and none of them works.

**C:>gem install mysql2**

**Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit... Building native extensions.**

**This could take a while... ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:**

**ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.**

**C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb checking for ruby/thread.h... no checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes checking for rb_intern3()... yes checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no checking for main() in -lm... yes checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no checking for main() in -lz... no checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no checking for main() in -lsocket... no checking for mysql_query() in
-lmysqlclient... no checking for main() in -lnsl... no checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no checking for main() in -lmygcc... no checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no**
 extconf.rb failed  **Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.**

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
        --with-mysql-config
        --without-mysql-config
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-mlib
        --without-mlib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-zlib
        --without-zlib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-socketlib
        --without-socketlib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-nsllib
        --without-nsllib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-mygcclib
        --without-mygcclib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9 .1/gems/mysql2-0.3.16 for inspection. Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.
3.16/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out

Comment: You should never use Windows for ruby on rails development. Lots of problems arise and very slow development time. Sometimes you even miss the necessary compilers, it's a hassle. I would recomment you install a linux much easier and you will setup your environments really easily.

Comment: Thanks for the adivice. Is there any problem of using linux on a Virtual Machine @MohamedOsama ??

Comment: It's still a hassle. If you don't assign enough memory for your VM then most probably it would lag a lot and after all a VM is not like a full running operating system. In Fedora for example, you will just `bundle install` and run `service mysqld start` and your mysql server will be running. COnfigure your database in `database.yml` and you won't worry about anything else.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014117/ruby-mysql2-gem-installation-on-windows-7