# Installing Mysql gem - failure to build native extension

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems

I have tried to install mysql on windows 7 (x64), but it output an error:

```
Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby MYSQL2 gem installation on windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014117/ruby-mysql2-gem-installation-on-windows-7)

Comment: Do you have [RubyInstaller Development Kit (DevKit)](http://dl.bintray.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe) installed on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

**1:** add `gem 'mysql2'` in Gemfile

**2:** remove `Gemfile.lock`

**3:** run `bundle install`

Would work !!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to install mysql client library:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

Comment: For more information [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014117/ruby-mysql2-gem-installation-on-windows-7?lq=1)