# Mysql Errors when trying to start Rails project with mysql database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rubygems, mysql2

I am trying to create a new Ruby Rails project on a Windows system

I have installed Rails v 7.1.1

I then run `rails new myRailsProject -d mysql`

However, an error occurs:

```
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.5), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  mysql2
         run  bundle lock --add-platform=x86_64-linux
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Resolving dependencies...
Writing lockfile to C:/Users/Me/RailsProjects/myRailsProject/Gemfile.lock
         run  bundle binstubs bundler
Could not find mysql2-0.5.5 in locally installed gems
       rails  importmap:install
Could not find mysql2-0.5.5 in locally installed gems
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
       rails  turbo:install stimulus:install
Could not find mysql2-0.5.5 in locally installed gems
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I then try to run `Bundle install` as per online forums

I get: `Could not locate Gemfile`

The rails directory has been created so I cd into it using `cd myRailsProject` and then run `bundle install` again. I still get an error:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Installing mysql2 0.5.5 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.5/ext/mysql2
C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_absint_size()... yes
checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... yes
checking for rb_gc_mark_movable()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enc_interned_str() in ruby.h... yes
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-openssl-dir
        --without-openssl-dir
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
        --with-mysql-config
        --without-mysql-config
        --with-mysqlclient-dir
        --without-mysqlclient-dir
        --with-mysqlclient-include
        --without-mysqlclient-include=${mysqlclient-dir}/include
        --with-mysqlclient-lib
        --without-mysqlclient-lib=${mysqlclient-dir}/lib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/mkmf.rb:1083:in `block in find_library': undefined
method `split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

    paths = paths.flat_map {|path| path.split(File::PATH_SEPARATOR)}
                                       ^^^^^^
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/mkmf.rb:1083:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/mkmf.rb:1083:in `flat_map'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/mkmf.rb:1083:in `find_library'
        from extconf.rb:131:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.2.0/mysql2-0.5.5/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.5 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.2.0/mysql2-0.5.5/gem_make.out

  C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:120:in `run'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:28:in
`build'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:188:in
`build_extension'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:222:in `block
in build_extensions'
  C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:219:in `each'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:219:in
`build_extensions'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/installer.rb:844:in
`build_extensions'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:72:in
`build_extensions'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in
`install'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:203:in
`install'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in
`install'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
`install_from_spec'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:130:in
`do_install'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:121:in
`block in worker_pool'
  C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in
process_queue'
  C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
  C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:90:in `block (2
levels) in create_threads'

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.5), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  mysql2
```

I'm not sure what is wrong. The Rails directory for my project is created, though it doesn't seem like the project is using mysql, and I can't run `bundle install`.

Comment: The error you're encountering while running bundle install in your Rails project indicates that the mysql2 gem could not be installed because the necessary MySQL library or server is not installed or not running on your system. Try installing and running MySQL in your local machine.

Comment: Thanks, but I have MySQL installed. I run `mysql --version` and get
`mysql  Ver 8.0.34 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)`. I also tried running `bundle install` with mysql running.

Comment: After long search I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014117/ruby-mysql2-gem-installation-on-windows-7/19023107#19023107 Had to download an archived version of mysql-connector. Not sure why or how it works but it worked.