# Ruby on rails server won't start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I'm trying to start a server on rails but it isn't working, any ideas on why that might be? I haven't edited the proyect, this is my first try at starting it. I've reinstalled gems and used bundle install with some different options, but all to no avail. I'm working on Windows.

```
C:\Users\Julián\Documents\Sites\simple_cms>rails server
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/comman
ds_tasks.rb:79:in `require': cannot load such file -- C:/Users/JuliÃ¡n/Documents/Sites/simple_cms/config/application (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

UPDATE:
I ran the same command on a new proyect located on another folder without any strange characters (Such as "á"), also unsuccessfully. Here's the new error.

```
C:\Users\Public\Sites\simple_cms>rails server
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `require': 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.0.0/mysql2-0.3.16/mysql2/mysql2.so (LoadError)

    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'        from C:/Users/Public/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Make sure that file is present at: C:/Users/JuliÃ¡n/Documents/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb

Comment: The file exists, it contains the following:

require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'rails/all'
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
module SimpleCms
  class Application < Rails::Application
  end
end

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `command_tasks.rb` cannot find your application file. It's probably because of the path name. `C:/Users/JuliÃ¡n/Documents/Sites/simple_cms/config/application` It looks like it mistook your name `Julián` for `JuliÃ¡n`

Comment: That's what i thought at first so I tried it again with a new folder on "Public" user, but I got the same error

Comment: Do you still have the output for the public user?

Comment: Looking at the new error do you have mysql installed?

Comment: It seems other people have had this problem and had to copy `libmysql.dll' to the ruby bin directory.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164818/loaderror-trying-to-use-mysql-with-ruby-on-rails-in-windows-rubymine-ide

Answer (score 0):

**Bundle Install**

Could be wrong, but certainly seems you have a lack of the `mysql2` gem, or the `mysql` files Rails needs to load your app.

Confirmation of this would come if you performed `bundle install` on your system - I surmise the `mysql` gem would fail

---

**MYSQL Gem**

Considering you're on Windows, you've probably not got the MYSQL2 gem installed - standard issue which we wrote a tutorial about [here](https://medium.com/p/a028f44d87f3):

> 1. Install any [MYSQL C-Connector Header files](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/) on your system
> 2. Install the `mysql2` gem with the relevant arguments
> 3. Copy the libmysql.dll file to your `ruby/bin` directory

The C-Connector header files are vital for Windows, as they allow your system to "read" the MYSQL commands / requests. These are not installed by default, so you have to install them yourself (it's only to install the gem, then you can get rid of them if you want):

[image: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/]

Install this file, then you can use the following install command:

```
gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-dir="C:\mysql-connector-path"'
```

This *should* install the gem on your system, which you'll then be able to finish by transferring `libmysql.dll` from your mysql files' `bin` directory to your `ruby/bin` directory:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

May be, in other way you should try virtual machine with Linux (Ubuntu).
I started first time rails with Windows but it was so hard to operate gems and environment.